# Is it possible to parse $_POST as $key => $value in table form to email

Tags: php, email

I am emailing form data, using

```
$message .= "IP Address : ";
$message .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$message .= $eol;
$logdata = '';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if (!in_array(strtolower($key), $internalfields))
    {
        if (!is_array($value))
        {
         $message .= ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $key)) . " : " . $value . $eol;
        }
        else
        {
         $message .= ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $key)) . " : " . implode(",", $value) . $eol;
        }
    }
}
```

> Is it possible to parse it in table form.
>   Currently i am getting result like;
>   NAME : nina
>   EMAIL: nina_20@gmail.com

Comment: What errors are you getting / what problems are you having?

Comment: $_POST GLOBAL variable is nothing but an array so you can use it

Comment: What did you try to make it `table form` ?

Comment: `$key = array_keys($_POST) ; $values = array_values($_POST);` now create `<th>` with `$key` and `<td>` with `$values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do that. Just add the table tag in the code, like this:

```
$message .= "<table>";
   foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
   {
         $message .= "<tr>";
      if (!in_array(strtolower($key), $internalfields))
      {
         if (!is_array($value))
         {
            $message .= "<td>".ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $key)) . "</td> <td> " . $value . "</td>";
         }
         else
         {
            $message .= "<td>".ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $key)) . "</td> <td> " . implode(",", $value) . "</td>";
         }
      }
      $message .= "</tr>";
   }
   $message .= "</table>";
```

Check the places of `table`, `tr` and `td`. You can place them according to your requirement.

Comment: Lovely, this was exactly what I wanted, Thanks to understand.
the only problem it is not converting $Key into uppercase.

Comment: @HMT use the `strtoupper` function instead of ucword. ucword will make the first latter of each word in upper case and `strtoupper` will convert the whole string in upper case.

Comment: @HMT accept the answer it solve the problem, thanks.

Comment: Thanks
Brother, This helps perfectly.

Comment: how to accept it.
i.e. where is the option.
i tried to vote up,  but it says that my reputation is low to show that vote, but they counted it.

Comment: @HMT There will be a check mark below the vote. Click on that check mark, it will convert into green after accept the answer

Comment: yeh, got it.
actually i am new, just ask the second question  in the community.